# Setting up Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS sever for home network using Samba 4.3.11

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, samba, file-sharing

Really struggling with this...

have followed the guide ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21 ) with no luck.

I have a home network with windows and mac os machines. Neither can connect to the ubuntu server at all. Goal is to have an ubuntu server that shares storage for the whole network.

Output of testparm:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[storage]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
server role = standalone server
security = USER
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
dns proxy = No
wins support = Yes
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
create mask = 0700
printable = Yes
browseable = No


[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[storage]
path = /mnt/storage
valid users = adrian
read only = No
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
directory mode = 0777
guest ok = Yes
```

Listing of all shares:

```
smbclient -L //192.168.0.210/storage -U adrian 
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter adrian's password:
```

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
storage         Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (server server (Samba, Ubuntu))
```

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
Server               Comment
---------            -------
SERVER               server server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            SERVER
```

Have looked up so many guides and tried many different combinations with no luck, hopefully I've missed something simple. Looking for help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try by suppressing the line `valid users = adrian`?  This would allow any user to access your `storage`.  Another point to control is wether the various machines belong to the '`WORKGROUP`.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I have suppressed that line and also checked the workgroup was correct. I would be happy even just to connect it to my mac laptop.. smb://192.168.0.210/storage only gives me connection failed.

While looking at troubleshooting options, I ran a ping test from the sever to the mac which was fine, however pinging the sever from the mac gives me request timeout... Has me even more confused.

Comment: This means there is a connection problem: either the mac does not aloow you to reach the server or the server does not allow incoming request.  Anyway, your problem is merely a network problem than a Samba problem.

Comment: @marc I connect to it via ssh just fine though? Perhaps your right, will look further into my network setup.